# Color reproduced on screen is different between platforms

Tags: android, ios, c, opengl-es

I have an both on the `Android` and `iOS`. Both are using the exact same render code with `OpenGL ES`. I noticed that even when using the same `RGBA` values, the colour reproduced on screen by the devices are not the same.

I want suggestions on what might be the cause. I have considered that it might be just the display hardware, and if so, how would you recommend handling this case and if this is usually handled at all.

Thanks.

Comment: how did you measure that they are different? it could just be the difference between LCD and OLED displays you are seeing...

Comment: I agree with Fonix , from my expirience there can be even difference between different android devices .

Answer (score 0):

Take a screenshot on both devices, email it to a PC and compare the actual colours in photoshop.

It's probably just the screen, they can vary wildly, I wouldn't worry about it unless your app has some special specific reason to be concerned about exact colour reproduction.

Even on a single device there are sometimes settings which change the look completely, e.g. the Samsung Galaxy S6: http://www.phonearena.com/news/Samsung-Galaxy-S6-Review-of-the-various-display-modes_id69968

Comment: Thanks. There isn't really a specific reason to produce accurate colors for this app. I am just curious for the cases where it is important, are we the developers expected to handle such cases and if so, how.